# Importing issue history from other issue tracker DB into Jira

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am importing issues from a non-legacy issue tracker systems DB into Jira.

I am able to import all the issues from the DB, properly with the help of customized 'jira-importer-plugin.jar'.Now I want to import the issue history of the non-legacy issue tracker into Jira.

Are there any workarounds for pushing the issue change history from other issue trackers into Jira.

Can anyone please tell me in detail how do I import history into Jira from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to customize the JIRA importer that you were using to also use the JIRA ChangeLogUtils and related classes to add the data to the change* tables in the JIRA database.